# Bash String how to remove characters before and after a colon

Tags: bash

I am not sure how to declare two variables from one string. The string is:

```
Tom:d04b98f48e8f8bcc15c6ae5ac050801cd6dcfd428fb5f9e65c4e16e7807340fa
```

I am hoping to declare 2 variables name and hash where:

```
echo "$name" 
OUTPUT - Tom
echo "$hash"
OUTPUT - d04b98f48e8f8bcc15c6ae5ac050801cd6dcfd428fb5f9e65c4e16e7807340fa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use shell [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
$ string="Tom:d04b98f48e8f8bcc15c6ae5ac050801cd6dcfd428fb5f9e65c4e16e7807340fa"
$ name="${string%:*}"
$ echo "$name"
Tom
$ hash="${string#*:}"
$ echo "$hash" # See note
d04b98f48e8f8bcc15c6ae5ac050801cd6dcfd428fb5f9e65c4e16e7807340fa
```

---

<sup>**A subtle note** : It is advised that you double quote variables to prevent word splitting.</sup>

Comment: @Jolan : Thanks for accepting the answer, do have a look at the note I have left for you.

Comment: Word splitting does not occur on the right-hand side of a variable assignment.

Comment: @chepner : I actually meant stripping of whitespaces in the beginning. Try `./script ' <- that is a space'` where script is `var=$1;echo "$var"` .

Comment: `script ' space'` outputs a leading space.

Comment: @chepner : But not in my shell which is `GNU bash, version 4.3.11`. It strips the initial spaces.

Comment: I very much doubt that.

Comment: @chepner : Hmm, I came across this recently.  Initially `$var` was not double quoted in `echo`, In that case trimming of initial space is understandable. But even after double quoting it, I got the same results.

Comment: The documentation explicitly omits word-splitting from the expansions applied to the right-hand side of an expansion, and I cannot reproduce what you claim to see with 3.2, 4.3, or 4.4,

Comment: @chepner : Hmm, mind giving me the link which says so, If this is probably a bug here, my note at the end would be misleading, so changed.

Comment: ["All values undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal (detailed below)."](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)

Comment: @chepner : Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Use `read`:

```
str=Tom:d04b98f48e8f8bcc15c6ae5ac050801cd6dcfd428fb5f9e65c4e16e7807340fa
IFS=: read name hash <<< "$str"
```